# WCF; what's the big deal?

Tags: wcf, architecture, web-services

I'm just about getting into [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation); but from what I've read so far, like the sample scenarios I found on MSDN and some other sites, I can do all that with [web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) and applications that call those web services. So why the need for an elaborate layer like WCF?

Most of the comparisons I've googled for explain it more from a programming point of view. Still trying to find answers without much success as to when it makes business and of course programming sense to use the WCF layer as opposed to traditional application to web services model.

Anyone here with experience on both and can advice on how to go about choosing either web services or going the WCF way? What are those things that can't absolutely be done using just plain old web services called by applications and where the WCF layer will save the day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924756/what-am-i-missing-about-wcf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've fallen for the Microsoft trap of "it's just about web services"  :-)

It's actually **a lot more**:

- it's about **service-oriented programming** in general (not just web services - you can also write TCP/IP based services, [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) queue-based messaging and a lot more)
- it's about **unifying** all the diverse programming models that existed so far (ASMX, Enterprise Services, DCOM, .NET remoting)
- it's about providing a lot of ready-made and **ready-to-use plumbing** which can handle things like reliable messaging, transaction support, security in any shape or form you'd like, service discovery, and a lot more
- it's about separating the service implementation from the details of how clients will call it and making this a configurable stack of protocols, encodings etc.

Sure - most of this stuff can be done in ASMX, or .NET remoting - but try to convert an ASMX web service to be callable in your intranet using TCP/IP and transport security...  Many of those "older" technologies have a very intricate and direct link to how they're being used - you can't easily change that without changing the whole service code.

WCF separates all these "plumbing details" like what endpoint to call, what protocol to use to call it, how to handle security etc. out into a "WCF stack" that's configurable and composable, so you can easily switch your service XYZ to use HTTP allowing anonymous users to call it, to using TCP/IP with Windows credentials required - your service code won't change a bit - it's only configuration of the plumbing.

That to me is the most compelling reason for WCF - I can totally concentrate on my actual service code, and not pollute it with lots of plumbing stuff - how to handle transports and text encodings and all that. And I can easily change that and adapt to new requirements and needs in deployment without having to touch my actual service code.

Plus, the second major point is extensibility - most of the older technologies just had their one, set way of doing things and many didn't lend themselves to being extended. You had to either adapt to use it the way they did it - or forget about it. WCF has a vast and very intricate system for extending just about anything - you can create your own transport protocol (people have created UDP or SMTP based bindings), you can create your own message encoders (like I had to do to talk to a web service which could only understand ISO-8859-1 encoded messages), and you can extend just about anything else in WCF - all in an organized, well-documented, very stable and safe way.

So these two things - separating out plumbing into configurable layers, and extensibility to the maximum - are the most compelling reasons for me to use WCF.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Kobi's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924756/what-am-i-missing-about-wcf) above, is a far better answer than mine.

WCF is basically a better architecture for supporting communications. It breaks many dependencies such as hosting (not iis dependent), transport, security, addressing into plugin components, and allows customisation to a very high degree.

Yes you can do a lot with traditional technologies, however you can do more with WCF. If you don't need the features now then of course you can can continue with legacy technologies, however if you prefer you can opt for a better architecture now with an eye on the future but it comes at a cost of having to switch technologies now.

Take this example. If you have a legacy asmx web service, how easily can you offer the same service via an MSMQed endpoint? With WCF its as simple as adding new config settings.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are not asking "why not just stick with SOAP/HTTP". WSF allows you to choose a number of different transports rather than just simple HTTP, but as you observe the WS-* technologies allow you to do all that. So I think you're asking why use a powerful but complex framework when the raw technolgies are not impossibly complex?

You could ask this same question of any Framework. You could just use the basic technologies and avoid the learning curve of adopting the framework.

Frameworks such as WCF do have a learning curve, but consider what happens if you don't use them:

You find that you write boiler-plate code for each service invocation. You then either accept duplication or begin to refactor and build your own libraries. Before long you've developed your own Framework, but it's not the same as anybody else's. So then any new team memeber has to learn your local framework, serious learning currve.

Note also that WCF addresses issues such as the monitoring of the deployed solution.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest appeal to me is [testability](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/02/10/WCF-Mocking-and-IoC-Oh-MY.aspx). Services are defined by a CLR interface, which is quite easy to mock inside a test harness. Some words of warning, however. With great flexibility comes some pain in the configuration process, along with a few "gotchas". An example of a gotcha is that WCF--adhering closely to a "best practice"--requires an active SSL connection in order to pass SOAP authentication credentials over HTTP. This hinders testing quite a bit.