# WCF vs ServiceStack

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm struggling with `WCF` over engineering.  It seems to me like a strange code layer, that do something useful, like giving you the possibility to call methods over http.

But in other hands, it increases useless code, useless methods calls, and so on.

Its like buying a japanese car, you will pay cheaper, but it will cost you more than you imagined.

Joking aside, I would like to know if I'm missing the real point here, or there is a better solution ?

Comment: Take some time to do some research. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924756/what-am-i-missing-about-wcf, for instance.

Comment: Already did. IMO it says basically that I have to live with it = [

Comment: Some differences between ServiceStack vs WCF at: http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack

Comment: Mythz, very thanks, seems a good article. I will read calmly, and post my insights later.